# printing text to webpage using python

Tags: python, web

I want to know; is this possible? I learnt HTML back in the early 00s, used to have the fundamentals of PHP and javascript. Now all I remember is basic HTML, and python. Currently I have a python script that prints to a GUI Tkinter entry on repeat every couple of seconds, as defined by the user.

I want to do *this* with a webpage.

Is it possible to print text to a dynamically updated webpage? I was thinking RSS feed.. which sure, would work. But it probably wouldn't be to neat. I want to recreate my Tkinter GUI on a page and make the 'flashcard' service available on the net. The python script retrieves values from an SQL Lite database. And as I hear python is net-safe, I don't want to learn an entirely new language such as PHP.

I would also like to embed the entire dynamically updated form in a drupal site if it's possible to do that. Any ideas? Example tutorials on using python to dynamically add text to a webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @fulhack recommends the CGI python module, and I personally have used this in the past, its not quite an optimal choice these days. Its pretty inefficient, since a new python process has to be started per request (if I remember correctly).

What you might want to do, to get yourself going down the right path to start, is take a look at the abundant choices for python web frameworks:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Some are quite large and full featured like django. While others are very lightweight and small. I hear flask is pretty light, though all I personally have much experience with is django. If you compare some of these and pick one that suits your needs, you may be a lot happier in the long run and and up learning a process that is reusable.

Comment: I spent a few hours this morning tinkering with django thanks to your response, and seem to have gotten pretty far (in as to with) getting a basic site template up and running, along with the CSS and formatting down.. I'm not sure quite how perfectly it works in terms of dynamically updating a page, but I find django-cms the perfect balance between retard-friendly and coder-friendly. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @abkai: What is your definition of dynamically updating a page? You can use the templates for server side dynamic pages, and javascript on the client side to dynamically grab other data, submit forms, etc. Could you explain more? Even php or other server side languages can only deliver the http response. To have the page dynamically update like a desktop gui, you need to be making ajax requests to the server constantly.

Comment: I may have the wrong definition, but ultimately using javascript to edit the contents of a <h1> on a button press, with a random selection (never the same thing twice) from an array created by the output of running a python script with arguments (that returns a list), that obtains the data from an sqlite database. Pretty simple, right? But I seem to be in wayy over my head. It's giving me a pretty bad headache :3 I suppose I don't need it to update like a desktop GUI at all, so I suppose I was using the incorrect term.

Comment: @abkai: yea there are some fundamental differences between doing that in your desktop app and a web app. A desktop app can have a thread constantly streaming that data and its all local. That constant python stream transforms into a url you would query with GET args, at intervals. There are more robust approaches like websockets or the newer html5 socket. But because you now have a client and server in different locations, your view has to keep asking for new remote data in an async request.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're trying to create a CGI script? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Here is a python specific tutorial for CGI programming: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm

Comment: Its worth mentioning though that the CGI approach with python is pretty dated and quite inefficient. Though the plus side is that all you need is python on the server, and cgi support, as opposed to setting up a framework. But it is more optimal to just pick a lightweight framework.

Comment: I still think its a good answer to point out the most straightforward option. It does still exist.